# CodeIgniter not properly inserting sql data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$idgen = uniqid(rand(), false);
$churchName = $this->input->post('church_name');
$streetAddress = $this->input->post('street_address');
$locationalCity = $this->input->post('locational_city');
$locationalState = $this->input->post('locational_state');
$locationalZip = $this->input->post('locational_zip');
$locationalCountry = $this->input->post('locational_country');
$taxNum = $this->input->post('tax_exemption_number');**

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO church_repo (church_name, street_address, locational_address, locational_zip, locational_country, locational_city, overseer_account_id, tax_exemption_number, status) VALUES('{$churchName}', '{$streetAddress}', '{$locationalCity}', '{$idgen}', '{$locationalState}', '{$locationalZip}', '{$locationalCountry}', '{$taxNum}', 'pending')");
```

The code above isn't inserting correctly, in Ci I'm getting the following error:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'locational_address' in 'field
>   list'
>
> INSERT INTO church_repo (church_name, street_address,
>   locational_address, locational_zip, locational_country,
>   locational_city, overseer_account_id, tax_exemption_number, status)
>   VALUES('bgtg', 'ff', 'rgfr', '270284f1eec6e5bfd4', 'rgrd', 'bdtbdt',
>   'United States of America', '84894894894', 'pending')
>
> Filename:
>   C:\Workspace\htdocs\Jan-2012\Gospel-links.org\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: there's no "locational_address" field, as already pointed out by d2byrke, so you should start by checking that.

Might be "**street_address**", maybe?

As an addendum, you're **not escaping** the values you enter in your DB; use query bindings, if you don't want to use Active Record:

```
$churchName = $this->input->post('church_name');
$streetAddress = $this->input->post('street_address');
$locationalCity = $this->input->post('locational_city');
$locationalState = $this->input->post('locational_state');
$locationalZip = $this->input->post('locational_zip');
$locationalCountry = $this->input->post('locational_country');
$taxNum = $this->input->post('tax_exemption_number');

$sql = "INSERT INTO church_repo(church_name, street_address, locational_address, locational_zip, locational_country, locational_city, overseer_account_id, tax_exemption_number, status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$this->db->query($sql, array($churchName,$streetAddress,$locationalCity,$locationalState,$locationalZip,$locationalChurch,$taxnum,'pending');
```

Or, even cleaner (and protected) with Active Record:

```
    $field['church_name'] = $this->input->post('church_name');
    $field['street_address'] = $this->input->post('street_address');
    $field['locational_city'] = $this->input->post('locational_city');
    $field['locational_state'] = $this->input->post('locational_state');
    $field['locational_zip'] = $this->input->post('locational_zip');
    $field['locational_country'] = $this->input->post('locational_country');
    $field['tax_exemption_num'] = $this->input->post('tax_exemption_number');
    $field['status'] = 'pending';
    $field['overseer_account_id'] = 'value here';

    $this->db->insert('church_repo', $field);
```

Where `$field` is an array with table names as index, and field values as value.

Comment: 'street_address' was non-existent.. thanks man. and btw how'd you know it was 'street_address' anyhow?

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby the variables you assigned the post to look like having the same name (camelCased) of your table cols ($churchName,$locationalCity..), it was much a game of "spot the differences" :)

Answer (score 3):

check your table attribute names, that error means that "locational_address" doesn't exist in your table.  may be just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Try this just changed the order or insert to mach with column

```
$idgen = uniqid(rand(), false);
$churchName = $this->input->post('church_name');
$streetAddress = $this->input->post('street_address');
$locationalCity = $this->input->post('locational_city');
$locationalState = $this->input->post('locational_state');
$locationalZip = $this->input->post('locational_zip');
$locationalCountry = $this->input->post('locational_country');
$taxNum = $this->input->post('tax_exemption_number');**

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO church_repo (church_name, street_address, locational_address, locational_zip, locational_country, locational_city, overseer_account_id, tax_exemption_number, status) VALUES('{$churchName}', '{$streetAddress}', '{$locationalCity}', '{$locationalZip}', '{$locationalState}', '{$locationalCountry}', '{$idgen}', '{$taxNum}', 'pending')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sanitizing/escaping that content you are inserting. If there is a ' or something else you'll hit an error. Make sure your DB really does contain locational_address. Copy/paste to make sure no typos.

I would consider changing to this, it's much easier to read and follow whats happening. And the data is properly escaped then.

```
$data = array(
   'church_name' => $this->input->post('church_name'),
   'street_address' => $this->input->post('street_address'),
   .....
   'tax_exemption_number' => $this->input->post('tax_exemption_number')
);

$this->db->insert('church_repo', $data);
```

Comment: Okay cool. I was actually trying to figure out how to array out post data but couldn't find anything. Thanks for this tip.